# Better legibility of Thymeleaf template

Tags: templates, thymeleaf

I created a lot of Thymeleaf templates during the last weeks, using both html5 and textual mode. In these templates I need to use a lot of `th:each` statements that iterate over the `Context` variables.

On these variables I ofter access their getters which in turn return other objects which I have to use getters on and so on.
In order to process the data returned I need to apply stuff like `strings.defaultString(...)`

All these combined statements make it difficult to read and comprehend what is going on. Many lines of my templates are so long that they can't be read without scrolling horizontally.

I searched for best practices but only found some that describe how to create ["base templates"](https://medium.com/@trevormydata/week-5-thymeleaf-with-spring-mvc-rapid-introduction-to-the-essentials-799f1fba8c07) that give general advice on using Thymeleaf in combination with Spring or mention how to include [common fragements](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-fragments).

Is there best practice how to format / wrap Thymeleaf statements without causing negative effects on created html or text (for example unwanted line breaks) ?

Comment: You can create variables using `th:with` so that you dont have to do frequent `objA.propB.propC`. So you assign `th:with="propB=${objA.propB}"`

Comment: Then creating reusable fragments in another good approach

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla good idea, mind creating an answer ?

Comment: I have created the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create variables using `th:with` so that you dont have to do frequent `objA.propB.propC`. So you assign `th:with="propB=${objA.propB}"`

Then creating reusable fragments with parameters in another good approach so any HTML which is getting repeated can be extracted into a fragment and the data required for that fragment can be passed as argument.

Update:

```
<div class="profile-user-info">
    <th:block th:insert='~{::profileInfoRow("Name", ${user.name}) }' />
    <th:block th:insert='~{::profileInfoRow("Age", ${user.age}) }' />
    <th:block th:insert='~{::profileInfoRow("Location", ${user.location}) }' />
</div>

<div th:fragment="profileInfoRow(label, value)">
  <div class="profile-info-row">
    <div class="profile-info-name">[[${label}]]</div>
    <div class="profile-info-value">[[${value}]]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So above is a simple way you can create a reusable section of HTML and then use thymeleaf directives to include the reusable section by passing in the values for  dynamic arguments.

Comment: Can you give an example for the latter ?